# Flexslider manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm working with Flexslider and I'm running into a bit of trouble with some of the controls.  I have a pretty simple configuration although I want to change the position of one of the direction arrows when the .flex-disabled class isn't present on it's adjacent control. First call is to flexslider, pretty typical. Then the second call is something I wrote but does not seem to fully function.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            var $flexslider = $('.flexslider');
                $flexslider.flexslider({
                  animation: "fade",
                  animationLoop: false,
                  animationSpeed: 500,
                  //controlsContainer: ".content",
                  directionNav: true,
                  manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li",
                  nextText: "View Next Property",
                  prevText: "View Previous Property",
                  slideshow: false

            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
            var previousControl = $('.flex-nav-prev a');
            var nextControl = $('.flex-nav-next a');

            if(previousControl.hasClass('.flex-disabled')){
                nextControl.parent().css('left','.5em')
            } else {
                nextControl.parent().css('left','5em')
            }       

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I guess to expand, The 'else' clause is the only thing getting executed.  it doesn't execute the primary 'if' clause at all.  Seems like something with they dynamic nature of the '.flex-disabled' class being applied isn't working with this function call.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the period in the if:

```
        if(previousControl.hasClass('flex-disabled')){
            nextControl.parent().css('left','.5em')
        } else {
            nextControl.parent().css('left','5em')
        }
```